# Blazor: FocusAsync is triggering click event

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor

I am new to blazor application and stuck on FocusAsync. I am using it on OnAfterRenderAsync. FocusAsync is actually firing a click instead of just focusing an element. Can anyone please advice?

```
//DialogComponent.razor
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @ref="YNnoButton"
             @onclick="No">No</button>

ElementReference YNnoButton;
[Parameter] public EventCallback<DialogResult> OnCancel { get; set; }

protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{

    await  SetFocus();


await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);

}
//setfocus 
public async Task SetFocus()
{
  await YNnoButton.FocusAsync();
}
//click event of No
private Task No()
{
    return OnCancel.InvokeAsync(DialogResult.No);
}
//MainComponenet.razor

@if (DialogIsOpen)
{
    Console.WriteLine("popup" + @Caption);
        <DialogComponent Caption="@Caption"
             Message="@DialogMessage"
             OnCancel="@onDialogClose"
             Type="@DialogButtonType"
             @ref="tmpDialog"
            DoFocus="@DoFocus"  >
                </DialogComponent>
}
@code{
private bool DialogIsOpen = false;
string DialogMessage = "";
string Caption = "";
DialogComponent.MessageBoxButtons DialogButtonType; //enum
 private void DisplayResults(){ 
        DialogIsOpen = true;
        Caption = "KG weight?";
        DialogMessage = "Is this the weight in KG?";
        DialogButtonType = 
                         DialogComponent.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
        DialogStep = 1;
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

basically, DisplayResults() will get called from another method of the componenet and it will open dialog component as a modal popup. on Dialog component I am trying to get the button to be focused but it actually gets clicked.

Comment: Have you used your JavaScript debugger to set a DOM event breakpoint to investigate yourself?

Comment: Can you simplify your code so we can reproduce? I tried it https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/wQOgFeks46kXIahF49 , but the issue doesn't appear.

Comment: @Alamakanambra so I have a same code, but this is a component, which opens a dialog box from another component. I am using it as below code  after setting all the parameters and using this.StateHasChanged(); would this be an issue?
    
    <DialogComponent Caption="@Caption"
                 Message="@DialogMessage"
                 OnCancel="@onDialogClose"
                 Type="@DialogButtonType"
                 @ref="tmpDialog"
                DoFocus="@DoFocus"  >
                    </DialogComponent>

Comment: @Dai yes I am using console.writeline since I haven't added javascript in my project.

Comment: I don't know how your dialog works. It may be something with StateHasChanged.. Can you post a code with this particular issue?

Comment: I have edited a question for more code @Alamakanambra

Comment: I still cannot see the issue... Can you create minimal sample with that issue using blazorrepl?

Comment: @Alamakanambra, I have reproduced the issue here: https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/ccaqlhPU07hasQhc16 I have to show a popup on textbox's enter key

Comment: As you describe incorrect behavior, it should just "click" the ` No`  button when the dialog appears? Nothing like that happens for me: https://imgur.com/a/jZPrKsK (or?)